# Помогите написать программу gawk, которая читает файл Си программы и записывает ее в другой файл как Python программу. Bash, Linux

Tags: linux, bash

Как перезаписать код на C в другой файл в формате Python ? Скрипт должен запускаться с терминала Linux. Код на С который нужно перезаписать:

```
int main(argv, **argc)
{
    i=5;
    while(i--) printf("i=%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Только такой код или произвольный код на Си?

Comment: @avp, мне нужно перезаписать етот код в формате Си с одного в другой файл в формат Python, то есть убрать фигурние скобки, і тд тп, перезаписать в синтаксис Python c помощью команды gawk, мне надо не рукчками ето перезаписать, а сделать специальний скрипт который ето сможет сделать

Comment: Вы понимаете, что в общем случае вам для начала нужно написать полный синтаксический разбор Си кода? Вряд ли awk лучший язык для этого занятия

Comment: @avp, да мне ето для университета, мне не нужно перезаписывать какой то большой проект, просто вот тот маленький фрагмент, есть команда gawk она может заменять слова или подстроки на нужные, и мне нужно только убрать те скобки и тд тп, но я не знаю как ето сделать